# 12VDC LED blinks when powered by a PD charger using a USB-C decoy module

Tags: power, led, charger, usb-c, trigger

I am trying to build a low-voltage LED lamp powered by a USB-C PD power adapter instead of a traditional DC power supply with a barrel connector. Several reasons for this:

- USB-C cable is detachable on both ends.
- USB-C cable can be ordered short or very long.
- USB-C power adapters are smaller, prettier, cheaper. Even non-GAN chargers are smaller, yet powerful.

In order to power the 12VDC LED with the correct voltage, I purchased a USB-C decoy module (or "trigger module") that automatically negotiates a voltage of 12V from the PD power adapter, then feeds the LED with that correct voltage.

The LED wattage is 8W; the power adapter is 20W (therefore not undersized). With a multimeter, I measured the output voltage of the decoy module with no load when connected to the power adapter: the trigger module indeed provides constant DC 12V. Great.

The problem occurs afterward, when the load is connected:

- **When the LED is the last item connected to the circuit after everything has been powered on already, it works.**
- **But when the LED is already plugged in before powering up the circuit (the normal way of doing things for a lamp…) it doesn't work: When switching on, the LED blinks constantly and the small blue status LED on the trigger module PCB does not even light up.**

I tried with two different USB-C decoy modules of different brands and designs: exact same result. I am at lost. Any clue and solution?

Comment: Did your "decoy modules" come with manuals or any description how they work and what kind of loads they can power? Does your LED come with a manual saying what kind of load it is? Even knowing if it is just a LED with resistors or LED with power supply or driver circuit might be enough to guess what goes wrong.

Comment: The LED is an OSRAM/LEDVANCE SUPERSTAR 50 MR16 GU5.3 8W 12VDC, 2700K dimmable, EAN 4058075613249
The USB decoy module is a Chinese PCB with no particular spec provided other than that it produces 12VDC output from a suitable USB-C PD power adapter, description here: https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005005163303655.html

Comment: And your PD supply can provide 12V, at how many amps or watts? But frankly, this is likely unsolvable, you have three random pieces of equipment (supply, Aliexpress bought mystery product, and LED globe with only description being volts and watts).

Comment: As said above, the PD supply wattage is 20W, it can provide a direct current of 1.67A @12V (this is also written directly on the charger case). The LED is 8W and draws 2.5 less current than the max the power supply can provide.

Comment: All this reminds of the blinking issue of 110-240VAC low-power LED that occur sometimes when the LED is powered with some "smart" Wi-Fi module in the wall box, and an additional "bypass" connected to the LED poles is mandatory to prevent this (that I think is some capacitor with perhaps other electronic components). Except here the circuit is low voltage direct current.

Comment: Exactly, those are the only things you know - the long term DC parameters. You don't know what kind of start-up current the LED bulb takes initially, such as consuming a lot of inrush current to charge capacitors. You don't know if the PD decoy module or PD supply can provide it. USB PD supplies are meant to power  devices that fall within USB specs regarding their start-up behaviour. They are not laboratory power supplies that can handle any random load you can think of. Likely LED consumes too much and PD supply overcurrent limit triggers and it shuts down, and restarts and shuts down again.

Comment: The thing that amazed me most is that all is perfectly working when the bulb is the last part connected. Thanks for the insight, the high inrush current is certainly a valid point. I will test again with a less powerful LED circa 4W.

Comment: I now see that OSRAM/LEDVANCE provide the inrush current for their 12V reflector LED lamps on their web site. Depending on the version, such inrush current is very high: 12.8 or 13.5A. Meaning that if the power supply delivers 12VDC, the peak consumed power is for a short instant as high as 150W or even a bit more than 160W! I think that the 20W power adapter (or maybe the USB decoy module) can't cope with that. That said, I wonder how a traditional LED driver whose rated power is often only 10% more than the nominal wattage of the lamp it feeds, is able to do it fine.

Comment: It's not about amps or watts itself. in theory plugging a discharged 100nF cap could have tens of amps surge but it is charged very quickly. For the USB power supply, it's about the energy and time. Putting too much capacitance to output, it will take too long with the output hitting a current limit to charge the voltage to be high enough that the overcurrent and undervoltage protections get triggered. Which is why it works if you let it boot up first and then connect the LED. USB power supplies are made to USB specs and  to be compatible with devices adhering to USB specs.

Comment: In short, USB supplies are not meant to be used as generic power supplies being able to start up and power any random arbitrary load you throw at it.